# Unable to focus input on embedded swf on page load in Opera

Tags: html, flash, input, focus, opera

I have a simple html file which is meant to display embedded flash where I can write straight from the start, withouth clicking on it earlier.
To my dissapointment, I can't do it in my favorite browser! Problem happen to occur only on Opera. On FF and Chrome works fine.

Here's the code:

    
              (...)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setFocus()
{   
    <!-- document.getElementById("clock-countdown").tabIndex = -1; -->
    document.getElementById("clock-countdown").focus(); 
}
</script>

</head>

<body onLoad="setFocus();">

<object name="clock-countdown" tabIndex="0"  > 
<embed id="clock-countdown" wmode="opaque" src="clock-countdown.swf"> </embed>
</object>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help to have an external script insert the object/embed into the DOM, to avoid the click-to-activate state. (Sorry about that.. :-/)